# Pass data between interfaces watchOS 2

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchkit, watchos-2

I had some difficulties passing data between 2 interface controllers on watchOS, here's my code:

INTERFACE CONTROLLER

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import CoreLocation


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager : CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()
    private var lat : Double!
    private var long : Double!



    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)
        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        self.locationManager.requestLocation()
        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()


    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        let currentLocation: CLLocation = locations[0]
        lat = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
        long = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError)
    {
        print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }

    override func contextForSegueWithIdentifier(segueIdentifier: String) -> AnyObject? {

            return [lat,long]
        }


}
```

DESTINATION CONTROLLER

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import MapKit
import CoreLocation


class ZEROPOINTFIVEInterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

   @IBOutlet var mapViewZ: WKInterfaceMap!
       let locationManager : CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    var lat: Double!
    var long: Double!



    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)
        if let strings = context as? [String] {
            lat = Double(strings[0])
            long = Double(strings[1])
        }
        let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: long)
        let coordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.2, longitudeDelta: 0.2)
        mapViewZ.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: coordinateSpan))

        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()


    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }

}
```

I want to pass lat and long. But it's nil when I run it in the simulator. Please help.

Comment: Can you try passing a known variable first? Like the a number or a string. If that works, you know its an issue with getting the lat/long (Are you simulating the location on simulator). If you can't receive the number or string, that means there is something wrong with you passing the data. Lmk what exactly the issue is.

Comment: it was the problem with passing data, the data itself it's fine. I just tested it.